# "text" on the tree node when it is partially visible

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, tooltip, treenode

How's the text(like below "Temporary ASP.NET") hovers directly over the tree node called? Any difference from tooltip?

Can it be controlled on visibility? e.g. do not display even when the node is partially visible.

[image]

pic: Windows Explorer

Thanks,

Comment: Did you write any code to show tool tips.

Comment: No. It seems a default behavior when node is partially visible. The screen shot is from Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can control this property, but not with a standard property.

If you override TreeView, and add a new CreateParams override, and add this code, then the tooltip won't appear:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
        parms.Style |= 0x80;  // Turn on TVS_NOTOOLTIPS
        return parms;
    }
}
```

[Code found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winforms/thread/00A91481-C931-4EFD-B289-AB1F7C79C96F)